# how to retrieve an image from database using image URL and insert it in grid view in vb. net?

Tags: vb.net, image, url, gridview

how to retrieve an image from database using image URL and insert it in grid view in vb. net  ??

thats my data base table

i have 3 columns in table image (ID as int , imageName as varchar , imageURL as varchar(max) i want to insert the image in a grid view but when i run this code i only get the last image in my table everytime

thats my code:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Dim dt As New DataTable()
Dim strConnString As [String] = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ConnectionString()
Dim strQuery As String = "select * from image"
Dim con As New SqlConnection(strConnString)
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(strQuery, con)
Dim sda As New SqlDataAdapter()
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd.Connection = con
    Try
        con.Open()
        sda.SelectCommand = cmd
        sda.Fill(dt)
        GridView1.DataSource = dt
        GridView1.DataBind()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Response.Write(ex.Message)
    Finally
        con.Close()
        sda.Dispose()
        con.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: and thats my gridView



<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns = "false"

       Font-Names = "Arial" 
        style="z-index: 1; left: 8px; top: 167px; position: absolute; height: 374px; width: 369px" >

    <Columns>

       <asp:BoundField DataField = "ID" HeaderText = "ID" />

       <asp:BoundField DataField = "FileName" HeaderText = "Image Name" />

       <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="FilePath" ControlStyle-Width="100"

        ControlStyle-Height = "100" HeaderText = "Preview Image"/>

    </Columns>

    </asp:GridView>

Answer (score 2):

you should have this column in the column definition of your GridView:

```
<asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="PictureURL"></asp:ImageField>
```

where PictureURL is the name of the column which contains the image url.

here there is a full example directly from MSDN:

[Displaying Images in a GridView Column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479350.aspx)

Comment: i have this column definition on the gridview for the picture URL

asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns = "false" Font-Names = "Arial" style="z-index: 1; left: 8px; top: 167px; position: absolute; height: 374px; width: 369px" > <Columns> <asp:BoundField DataField = "ID" HeaderText = "ID" /> <asp:BoundField DataField = "FileName" HeaderText = "Image Name" /> <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="FilePath" ControlStyle-Width="100" ControlStyle-Height = "100" HeaderText = "Preview Image"/> </Columns> </asp:GridView>

Comment: do you see the data in the grid or nothing is returned? what is the value of FilePath you retrieve?

Comment: yes i see the whole data from the DB in the gridview columns except that i always have the last image retrieved from the DB in the column "Preview image"

Comment: values of FilePath is : ~/images/img01.gif

Comment: you should check the table content in SQL management studio executing the same query as above.

Comment: i did thats what is retruned

1 img01.gif ~/images/img01.gif
2 pearl-necklace-4.jpg ~/images/pearl-necklace-4.jpg
4 img04.jpg ~/images/img04.jpg